# C++ string array split after 20 Bytes

Tags: c++, bluetooth-lowenergy, arduino-ide, notify, mtu

I have this code example that is used for making a 20 Byte size packets of data that will eventually will be sent via BLE. I want to change the code so I can input array of my data (accelerometer readings).

My data:

```
float ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz, yaw, pitch, roll;
char myConcatenation[80];
sprintf(myConcatenation, "%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f", ax,  ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz, yaw, pitch, roll);
```

The function definition:

```
std::vector<std::string> buildPackets(std::string data, size_t packetSize) {
  // split up the packet
  size_t partialPacketSize = packetSize - 4;

  // calculate how many packets
  size_t packetCount = data.length() / partialPacketSize;
  packetCount = data.length() % partialPacketSize == 0 ? packetCount : packetCount + 1;

  std::vector<std::string> packets;
  // construct each packet
  for (int i = 0; i < packetCount; i++) {
    // start of packet
    std::string packet = "##";
    packet += (char)packetCount;
    packet += (char)(i + 1);
    std::string part = i == packetCount - 1 ? data.substr(i * partialPacketSize) : data.substr(i * partialPacketSize, partialPacketSize);
    packet.append(part);

    // add to vector of packets
    packets.push_back(packet);
  }
```

Function call:
variable `data` here is string, all I need is put there my `myConcatenation[]`

What changes should I make in code for having it working?

```
   std::string data = "averylongstringofdatathatislargerthantwentycharacters";
size_t chars = data.length();
size_t packetSize = 20;

// assume I have this characteristic already setup
if (chars > packetSize) {
  auto packets = buildPackets(data, packetSize);
  for (auto packet : packets) {
    txCharacteristic->setValue(packet);
    txCharacteristic->notify();
  }
}
else {
  txCharacteristic->setValue(data);
  txCharacteristic->notify();
}
```

Thank you for any help.

---

EDIT:

```
this is what I have now: 

std::vector<std::string> buildPackets(std::string data, size_t packetSize) {
  // split up the packet
  size_t partialPacketSize = packetSize - 4;

  // calculate how many packets
  size_t packetCount = data.length() / partialPacketSize;
  packetCount = data.length() % partialPacketSize == 0 ? packetCount : packetCount + 1;

  std::vector<std::string> packets;
  // construct each packet
  for (int i = 0; i < packetCount; i++) {
    // start of packet
    std::string packet = "@";
    packet += (char)packetCount;
    packet += (char)(i + 1);
    std::string part = i == packetCount - 1 ? data.substr(i * partialPacketSize) : data.substr(i * partialPacketSize, partialPacketSize);
    packet.append(part);

    // add to vector of packets
    packets.push_back(packet);
  }

  return packets;
}


--------
**call function**

sprintf(myConcatenation, "#%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,#%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,#%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,#%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f", ax,  ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz, yaw, pitch, roll);

size_t packetSize = 20;

auto packets = buildPackets(myConcatenation, packetSize);
  for (auto packet : packets) {
    pCharacteristic->setValue(packet);
    pCharacteristic->notify();
  }

  Serial.println(myConcatenation);
```

---

Can I ask you about the receiving side? my string has `#` at the beginning of every different sensor reading (#ax,ay,az,#gx,gy...) and `@` on the start of every packet. Do you know how should be the receiving side implemented (I do that in MITAppInventor but I can't think of an idea how to connect the packetst in order and append them into .csv file. (each column = different data).

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, I want to note here that you should think about increasing your MTU size. Splitting strings every 20 bytes seems really inefficient. Most devices nowadays support much bigger MTU sizes, if the central device requests that. On Android the app must trigger the MTU size negotiation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String class provides a constructor that takes in input a const char*, so you can use it for converting (implicitly or explicitly) your variable named data into a std::string.

So at the end, just pass it to the function

`float ax, ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz, yaw, pitch, roll;
char myConcatenation[80];
sprintf(myConcatenation, "%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f,%3.2f", ax,  ay, az, gx, gy, gz, mx, my, mz, yaw, pitch, roll);
auto packets = buildPackets(myConcatenation, packetSize);`

That's all.

A quick additional suggestion:

- change sprintf with sprintf_s, it's safer

[string reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Comment: Hello Mauro I tried to use your reference so I made new variable

`std::string myConcatenation[80];`

But now I am getting this error:

`cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::string* {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*}' to 'char*' for argument '1' to 'int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)'`

Should I change the datatype even in a function declaration?

Comment: Hi Boris, you don't need to change the type of myConcatenation, the cast will be done implicitly when you call the function buildPackets. Additionally, with that declaration, your variable is an array of 80 different strings, and you don t need them definitely :)

Comment: Hi Mauro, thank you for your help. It works and I am receiving packets the way I should but I don't know how to add them together on the receiving side. I changed my question according to that problem.

Comment: Hi, ok...could you please post some code related to the receiver? Let's see what you already have and how to modity it

Comment: hello Mauro, fortunately, I already solved my problem by changing the MTU limit. I am making my app in MITappInventor so I don't have any code.

Comment: Hi; glad to hear that. So in that case, if you re good enoguh you can just mark as accepted my answer as is, thanks